# Return a response from KernelEvents::CONTROLLER subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm implementing a controller filter using this pattern:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#creating-an-event-listener

However, instead of throwing an HTTP exception I would like to return a response.

How can I do that? What's the best/most acceptable way in SF2?

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $controller = $event->getController();

    // $controller passed can be either a class or a Closure.
    // This is not usual in Symfony but it may happen.
    // If it is a class, it comes in array format
    if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
    }

    if ($controller[0] instanceof ResourceServerAuthorizedController) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $response = $this->resourceServer->authorize($request);
        if (!$response->isOk()) {
            return $response; // ??? HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand, `return $response` is a response. Or create another response `return new Response('No authorized')`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to manipulate response for any given reason, you can do something like below which has some generic logic. You need to implement whatever else you want to do with it.

If you look for `onKernelController` in http://www.inanzzz.com/ site, you'll find 7 examples where it was used.

```
services:
    application_frontend.listener.player:
        class: Application\FrontendBundle\Listener\PlayerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

LISTENER

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

....

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $controller = $event->getController();
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$controller[0] instanceof YourController) {
            return;
        }

        $message = 'Bye inanzzz';

        $event->setController(
            function() use ($message) {
                return new Response($message, 200);
            }
        );
    }

....
```

Answer (score 1):

At this level of **kernel.controller** you can't manipulate the response (for this you need **kernel.response**, and you need to use **setResponse** method
- but there you can't verify the controller type).
If you really need the controller type what you can do in this case is changing the controller with any callable:

```
$replacementController = new ReplacementController();
$event->setController($replacementController->getReplacementMethod());
```

Hope this answers to your question.